# Executing function at specified time

Tags: python

I want to execute some code at 12 o clock everyday. The only way I can think todo this is to

1. sleep until 12 o clock
2. execute code
3. sleep 24 hours (minus time takes to run code)
4. goto 2

Is there a built in API I could use to schedule events like this?

*I cannot use cron jobs or anything similar, this must be in a python script*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[threading.Timer](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would work for you

```
import threading
def latercomer():
    print "Oops I am Late"

t = threading.Timer(30.0, latercomer)
t.start()
```

latecomer will be called after 30 secs

Comment: what if I want it to run at certain time? not certain interval?

Answer (score 1):

I think this [package](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) will be useful for your case.

```
pip install schedule
```

And here is the snippet of the code from the documentation:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```