# Using the input function to specify the time for a shutdown

Tags: python

Edit the script to use the input() function to query the user for the shutdown timeout period. Edit the script to use another input() function to query the user for a message to display as the machine executes the shutdown. I am having problems using the input function to ask the user for a time to shutdown the computer and also asking them for a message to display.

```
import os

#chkdsk = "chkdsk C:"
#os.system(chkdsk)

print("How much time till shutdown?")
time = input() 
print (time)

shutdown = 'shutdown", "-f", "-r", "-t", "-c", MESSAGE HERE'
os.system(shutdown)
```

Comment: *I am having problems using the input function...* What specific problem(s)? (Hint: you should include this information in the question itself, and all future questions you might ask here.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178927/executing-function-at-specified-time?rq=1

Comment: FWIW, you should pass the input prompt as an arg to the `input` function rather than using `print`. BTW, you're missing a `"` before `shutdown`. And you shouldn't use `time` as a variable name because that's the name of a standard module. Using it as a variable name makes your code confusing to read.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correctly: You want to put the time inside the string?

```
shutdown = 'shutdown -f -r -t {time} -c MESSAGE HERE'
os.system(shutdown.format(time=time))
```

Comment: Yes. I want to ask the user for a time and then insert it in the shutdown command.

Comment: Yes. I tried your code but it still did not execute properly. After entering in the time and message input the help page for shutdown popped up.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use that line:

```
x = int(input("How much time till shutdown?"))
```